# How to make accordion doesn't work and tell me Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined if element existed?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

This is what I have at the moment. This code doesn't work as it should.

I need to make that - if I press for header element section must disappear, when I press again it must appear. I don't understand why it tells me that element undefined if it existed in HTML.... Can anyone help me with this problem please?

```js
var filterTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-form h3');
var filterSection = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-section');
var filterInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-inputs');

for (var j = 0; j < filterTrigger.length; j++) {
  filterInputs[j].classList.add('filter-hidden');
  filterTrigger[j].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    filterSection[j].classList.toggle('catalog__filter-section--opened');
    filterInputs[j].classList.toggle('filter-visible');
  });
}
```

```css
.catalog__container {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.catalog__content-container {
  margin-left: 7.2%;
  margin-right: 7.2%;
  margin-top: 91px;
}

.catalog__filter-form {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  width: 248px;
}

.catalog__filter-form h3 {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.catalog__filter-section {
  padding-left: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid brown;
  position: relative;
}

.catalog__filter-section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: -38px;
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-down-icon.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18px;
  height: 12px;
}

.catalog__filter-section--opened::after {
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-up-icon.svg")
}

.catalog__filter-section:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.catalog__filter-inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.catalog__filter-section label {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.catalog__filter-section input {
  appearance: none;
}

.catalog__filter-section input:checked+span {
  background-color: brown;
}

.catalog__filter-section span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background-color: white;
}

.filter-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.filter-visible {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form class="catalog__filter-form">
  <h3>Product</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section catalog__filter-section--opened" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs filter-visible">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Necklaces" checked>
        <span></span>
        Necklaces
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Chokers" checked>
        <span></span>
        Chokers
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Rings">
        <span></span>
        Rings
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Earrings" checked>
          <span></span>
          Earrings
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Material</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Gold">
        <span></span>
        Gold
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Silver">
        <span></span>
        Silver
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Collection</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="Pink flamingo">
        <span></span>
        Pink flamingo
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="Dreams">
        <span></span>
        Dreams
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Price</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Necklaces">
        Necklaces
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because function run when you click on h3 to hide child and at that time j will be 4.

you most create a const variable and store element in it.

```js
var filterTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-form h3');
var filterSection = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-section');
var filterInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-inputs');

function onClick(event, secEl, inpEl){
    event.preventDefault();
    secEl.classList.toggle('catalog__filter-section--opened');
    inpEl.classList.toggle('filter-visible');
  }

for (var j = 0; j < filterTrigger.length; j++) {
  const secEl = filterSection[j]
  const inpEl = filterInputs[j]
  filterInputs[j].classList.add('filter-hidden');
  filterTrigger[j].addEventListener('click', function(e){ onClick(e, secEl, inpEl) });
}
```

```css
.catalog__container {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.catalog__content-container {
  margin-left: 7.2%;
  margin-right: 7.2%;
  margin-top: 91px;
}

.catalog__filter-form {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  width: 248px;
}

.catalog__filter-form h3 {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.catalog__filter-section {
  padding-left: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid brown;
  position: relative;
}

.catalog__filter-section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: -38px;
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-down-icon.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18px;
  height: 12px;
}

.catalog__filter-section--opened::after {
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-up-icon.svg")
}

.catalog__filter-section:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.catalog__filter-inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.catalog__filter-section label {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.catalog__filter-section input {
  appearance: none;
}

.catalog__filter-section input:checked+span {
  background-color: brown;
}

.catalog__filter-section span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background-color: white;
}

.filter-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.filter-visible {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form class="catalog__filter-form">
  <h3>Product</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section catalog__filter-section--opened" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs filter-visible">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Necklaces" checked>
        <span></span>
        Necklaces
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Chokers" checked>
        <span></span>
        Chokers
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Rings">
        <span></span>
        Rings
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Earrings" checked>
          <span></span>
          Earrings
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Material</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Gold">
        <span></span>
        Gold
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Silver">
        <span></span>
        Silver
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Collection</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="Pink flamingo">
        <span></span>
        Pink flamingo
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="Dreams">
        <span></span>
        Dreams
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Price</h3>
  <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
    <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Necklaces">
        Necklaces
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not trivial, but here you are

1. Added trigger class to the trigger h3
2. Close all on load
3. Delegate from the container div
4. Add some missing html (spans to the last checkbox)

```js
var filterSections = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-section');
var filterInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__filter-inputs');
const closeAll = () => {
  filterInputs.forEach((inp, i) => inp.classList.add('filter-hidden'));
  filterSections.forEach((section, i) => section.classList.remove('catalog__filter-section--opened'));
}
closeAll()
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.classList.contains("trigger")) return
  const filterSection = tgt.nextElementSibling;
  const filterInput = filterSection.querySelector(".catalog__filter-inputs");
  closeAll();
  filterSection.classList.toggle('catalog__filter-section--opened');
  filterInput.classList.toggle('filter-visible');
});
```

```css
.catalog__container {
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.catalog__content-container {
  margin-left: 7.2%;
  margin-right: 7.2%;
  margin-top: 91px;
}

.catalog__filter-form {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  width: 248px;
}

.catalog__filter-form h3 {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.catalog__filter-section {
  padding-left: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid brown;
  position: relative;
}

.catalog__filter-section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: -38px;
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-down-icon.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18px;
  height: 12px;
}

.catalog__filter-section--opened::after {
  background-image: url("../img/arrow-up-icon.svg")
}

.catalog__filter-section:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.catalog__filter-inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.catalog__filter-section label {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.catalog__filter-section input {
  appearance: none;
}

.catalog__filter-section input:checked+span {
  background-color: brown;
}

.catalog__filter-section span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background-color: white;
}

.filter-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.filter-visible {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form class="catalog__filter-form">
    <h3>Product</h3>
    <div class="catalog__filter-section catalog__filter-section--opened" tabindex="0">
      <div class="catalog__filter-inputs filter-visible">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Necklaces" checked>
        <span></span>
        Necklaces
      </label>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Chokers" checked>
        <span></span>
        Chokers
      </label>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Rings">
        <span></span>
        Rings
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Earrings" checked>
        <span></span>
        Earrings
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="trigger">Material</h3>
    <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
      <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Gold">
        <span></span>
        Gold
      </label>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Silver">
        <span></span>
        Silver
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="trigger">Collection</h3>
    <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
      <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="Pink flamingo">
        <span></span>
        Pink flamingo
      </label>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="Dreams">
        <span></span>
        Dreams
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="trigger">Price</h3>
    <div class="catalog__filter-section" tabindex="0">
      <div class="catalog__filter-inputs">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="Necklaces">
        <span></span>
        Necklaces
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```